# Pass dynamic table name to SQL function and return comma delimited string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dynamic, concatenation

**mytable structure**: id int, lookuptablename varchar

```
1, 'lookuptable1'
2, 'lookuptable2'
```

**lookuptable1**: id int, item varchar

```
1, 'item1 from lkt1'
2, 'item2 from lkt1'
```

**lookuptable2**: id int, item varchar

```
1, 'item1 from lkt2'
2, 'item2 from lkt2'
```

Query:

```
SELECT GetDelimitedList(lookuptablename) FROM mytable;
```

Expected result:

```
1,2~item1 from lkt1,item2 from lkt1
1,2~item1 from lkt2,item2 from lkt2
```

I have been struggling to find out a way to accomplish this in various ways but just couldn't figure it out.

Comment: And you want the ID and ITEM mashed into a single string, comma delimited and tilde separated?

Comment: You cannot do this with a dynamic table name and a UDF. A stored proc, yes, but is a stored proc an option?

Comment: http://explainextended.com/2010/06/21/group_concat-in-sql-server/

Comment: @Richard, if you look at his definition closely, tablename is a column in the first table `mytable`. Poorly chosen example names ftw!

Comment: @Kevin - But is the contents of the table referred to in that column which are required so still needs dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Kevin I realise that, but you still cannot construct dynamic SQL in UDFs, so it does not matter that it comes from a table

Comment: @Martin @Richard, Gocha.

Comment: Sorry for the lame example, I just updated the example tables and results.

I created a stored procedure to return the desired result as this:
EXEC ('INSERT INTO #temp SELECT intnum, id FROM ' + @tablename)

SELECT @id = COALESCE(@id + ',', '') + CONVERT(varchar,t.id)
 ,@item = COALESCE(@item + '~', '') + t.item
 FROM #temp z

But I need a function to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround. UDFs won't work.  Maybe CLR, but not native SQL UDF.

First create this proc, which mashes a table into a single row

```
create proc dbo.GetDelimitedList
@tablename sysname
AS
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = '
declare @id nvarchar(max), @item nvarchar(max)
select
    @id = isnull(@id+'','','''') + convert(varchar,id),
    @item = isnull(@item+'','','''') + item
from ' + quotename(@tablename) + '
select @id + ''~'' + @item'
exec (@sql)
GO
```

Then use this SQL batch to produce the output equivalent to `SELECT GetDelimitedList(tablename) FROM mytable;`

```
declare @tmp table(id int, mashed nvarchar(max))
declare @id int, @tablename sysname
-- start at first table
select top 1 @id = id, @tablename = tablename
from mytable
order by id asc
while @@ROWCOUNT > 0
begin
    -- fill our temp table
    insert @tmp (mashed) exec GetDelimitedList 'mytablelist'
    update @tmp set id = @id where id is null
    -- next table
    select top 1 @id=id, @tablename = tablename
    from mytable
    where id > @id
    order by id asc
end
SELECT * FROM @tmp;
```

Sample tables used:

```
create table mytable(id int, tablename varchar(100))
insert mytable values (1, 'mytablelist')
insert mytable values (3, 'mytablelist2')

create table mytablelist(id int, item varchar(100))
insert mytablelist values
(1, 'item1'),
(2, 'item2')
GO

create table mytablelist2(id int, item varchar(100))
insert mytablelist2 values
(11, 't2item1'),
(22, 't2item2')
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

For posterity's sake, dynamic Sql should generally be parameterizeable (even though it's unnecessary here) and executed via sp_executesql.  Full details on EXEC vs. sp_executesql can be found in this (excellent) article:

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Combining Erland's suggestions for error handling with his suggestions for writing dynamic stored procedures, yields a template similar to the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_<>]
(
    @isDebug BIT = 0
)
AS
BEGIN TRY

    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    SET XACT_ABORT ON 

    DECLARE
        @nvQry NVARCHAR(MAX)        = NULL,
        @nvParams NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
        @n NVARCHAR(MAX)                = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)

    -- %% Setup query here %% --

    IF @isDebug = 1
    BEGIN
        PRINT N'DECLARE ' + @n + @nvParams + @n + @n
        PRINT @nvQry
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_executesql @nvQry, @nvParams, 
    END 

    RETURN 0 --No Error

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Indicate that we want to rollback entire transaction stack, 
    --  (all BEGIN TRANSACTION calls increment @@TRANCOUNT and ROLLBACK
    --      TRANSACTION returns @@TRANCOUNT to zero)
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        -- Justified here: http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-II.html#rollbackornot
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END

    -- Augement error message and re-raise
  EXECUTE [dbo].[prc_ErrorHandler]

    -- In case this is only a statement-termination
    RETURN -1 -- Arbitrary error return value

END CATCH
GO
```

In the case of the question and to build upon @RichardTheKiwi's answer, we end up with an admittedly functionally equivalent procedure to the one above that is a little more debuggable:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDelimitedList]
(
    @tablename NVARCHAR(128),
    @isDebug BIT = 0
)
AS
BEGIN TRY

    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    SET XACT_ABORT ON 

    DECLARE
        @nvQry NVARCHAR(MAX)        = NULL,
        @nvParams NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
        @n NVARCHAR(MAX)                = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)

    -- %% Setup query here %% --
    SELECT
         @nvQry = 
            N'DECLARE ' + @n +
            N'  @id NVARCHAR(MAX), ' + @n +
            N'  @item NVARCHAR(MAX) ' + @n +
            N' ' + @n +
            N'SELECT ' + @n +
            N'  @id = ISNULL(@id + '','', '''') + CONVERT(VARCHAR, [id]), ' + @n +
            N'  @item = ISNULL(@item + '','', '''') + [item] ' + @n +
            N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tablename) + @n +
            N' ' + @n +
            N'SELECT @id + ''~'' + @item'

    IF @isDebug = 1
    BEGIN
        PRINT @nvQry
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_executesql @nvQry
    END 

    RETURN 0 --No Error

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Indicate that we want to rollback entire transaction stack, 
    --  (all BEGIN TRANSACTION calls increment @@TRANCOUNT and ROLLBACK
    --      TRANSACTION returns @@TRANCOUNT to zero)
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        -- Justified here: http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-II.html#rollbackornot
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END

    -- Augement error message and re-raise
  EXECUTE [dbo].[prc_ErrorHandler]

    -- In case this is only a statement-termination
    RETURN -1 -- Arbitrary error return value

END CATCH
GO
```